# Construction of binary random variable

Tags: probability-theory, sampling

We throw two coins in a row and thus get the event space $\{ZZ, WW, ZW, WZ\}$. 
Each of the 4 elementary events has a probability $1/4$.
how can I construct 3 binary random variable $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ about this event space, which are 2-fold independent, but not independent.

Comment: That's a basic exercise in stochastics. What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: one solution has two of the random variables being the two coin tosses.

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed. I am a stud in terms stochastics.

Comment: @Queue You can't expect us to solve the exercise for you. Make sure that you understand what the question is asking. If you don't understand some of the terms, ask.

Answer (score 4):

Let $E = \{ZZ,WW,ZW,WZ\}$. A *binary random variable* is a mapping $X\colon E \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. The *probability* of an event, say $X=0$, is defined as
$$ \Pr[X = 0] =\frac{|\{e \in E : X(e) = 0\}|}{4}. $$
For example, let $C_1(ZZ)=C_1(ZW) = 0$, $C_1(WZ)=C_1(WW) = 1$. Then $\Pr[C_1=0]=1/2$.

Two (binary) random variables $X_1,X_2$ are *independent* if for every $b_1,b_2 \in \{0,1\}$,
$$\Pr[X_1 = b_1 \text{ and } X_2 = b_2] = \Pr[X_1 = b_1] \Pr[X_2 = b_2]. $$
For example, if $C_2(ZZ) = C_2(WZ) = 0$ and $C_2(ZW) = C_2(WW) = 1$, then you can check that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are independent, by checking that $\Pr[C_1 = b] = \Pr[C_2 = b] = 1/2$ and $\Pr[C_1 = b_1 \text{ and } C_2 = b_2] = 1/4$. On the other hand, $C_1$ and $C_1$ are not independent since $\Pr[C_1 = 0 \text{ and } C_1 = 0] = 1/2$.

Similarly you can define when more than two random variables are independent. It should be clear that there are no three binary random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ with $\Pr[X_1 = 0] = \Pr[X_2 = 0] = \Pr[X_3 = 0] = 1/2$ which are independent, since that would imply $\Pr[X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = 0] = 1/8$, which is impossible (the only values that $\Pr$ can obtain are $0,1/4,1/2,3/4,1$). On the other hand, any three constant random variables are independent.

A set of random variables is $k$-wise independent if any $k$ of them are independent. The question asks you to find three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ so that any two are independent, but all three aren't. My hint is that there is a solution with $X_1 = C_1$ and $X_2 = C_2$.

Comment: hmm and X3 = c2?

Comment: Yuval's answer is excellent. So here is only one remark. Following this answer you are left with filling a table with zeros and ones. The table has 4 columns for ZZ,ZW,WZ,WW - and 3 rows for your 3 random variables. Try to fill the table such that every row contains two ``1``s and such that if you add any two  rows (vector-wise), there is exactly one ``2``.

Comment: $X_3 = C_2$ doesn't work since $X_2,X_3 = C_2,C_2$ are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an Exclusive-OR gate with inputs (logical variables)
$x$ and $y$ and output $z = x\oplus y$. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are equally 
likely to take on values $0$ and $1$ and are *independent*, that is
$$P\{x = a, y = b\} = P\{x = a\}P\{y = b\} = \frac{1}{4} ~~\text{for all}
~a, b \in \{0,1\}.$$
Then, $P\{z = 1\} = P\{x = 1, y = 0\} + P\{x=0, y = 1\} = \frac{1}{2}$ and so
$$P\{x = 1, z = 1\} = P\{x = 1, x\oplus y = 1\}
= P\{x = 1, y = 0\} = \frac{1}{4} = P\{x = 1\}P\{z=1\},$$
that is, $x$ and $z$ are also independent. Thus, we are led to the
remarkable conclusion that the *output* $z$ of an Exclusive-OR gate is
*independent* of its *input* $x$. A similar calculation shows that the
output $z$ is also independent of input $y$, that is, the output of
an Exclusive-OR gate is independent of its inputs!

> Lest we accept the moral principle that the output of an Exclusive-OR
>   gate does not depend on its inputs, let me say that this independence
>   disappears if $P\{x = 1\}$ is *not exactly* $\frac{1}{2}$ but differs
>   from $\frac{1}{2}$ by even an infinitesimal amount.

Comment: "moral principle" -- huh?

Comment: @Raphael I would have called it a Declaration of Independence if that term were not used elsewhere. The word _independence_ has two different meanings in this problem. $x$ and $y$ might be _physically independent_ meaning that they arise from sources that have nothing to do with each other. In this case, the model captures this by setting $P\{x=1,y=1\}=P\{x=1\}P\{y=1\}$ regardless of what $P\{x=1\}$ and $P\{y=1\}$ are. On the other hand, the independence of $x$ and $z$ is _stochastic independence_ and is an artifact of the assignment of the values of $P\{x=1\}$ and $P\{y=1\}$; (continued)

Comment: @Raphael as I noted, takea different value for $P\{x=1\}$ and the independence disappears. This fact is often forgotten by some who then infer the existence of physical independence from the observed stochastic independence. The output of an Exclusive-OR gate _always does_ depend physically on its inputs, but can be _stochastically independent_ for suitable choice of probabilities. Physical independence is captured in the probability model as stochastic independence but proof of stochastic independence should not be used to infer physical independence, which I suggested, tongue-in-cheek, holds

Comment: @Dilip It may be that the physically generated entities are $x$ and $z$, and $y$ is computed by $y=x\oplus z$. The situation is entirely symmetric. Or perhaps $x,y,z$ are generated independently, but you only observe the result if $x\oplus y\oplus z=0$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I regret that I am unable to understand what is meant by your comment and how it applies to my answer in which $z$ is the output of an XOR gate with inputs $x$ and $y$. Yes, $y = x \oplus z$ since $z = x\oplus y$, but the XOR gate does not _compute_ $y$ from $x$ and $z$.

Comment: @Dilip I'm just saying that $y = x \oplus z$ is one interpretation of the situation, which is completely indistinguishable from the other situations.